# Gradle - How to Fail on Major Version Conflict?

Tags: gradle, gradle-experimental, gradle-dependencies

If my project requires dependency `com.abc:xyz:1.2.0`, and I have another dependency that transitively wants `com.abc:xyz:2.0.0`, this is a major problem because even if my project compiles, there could be behavior differences. For some reason in this case, Gradle assumes that using 2.0.0 will be no problem at all and chooses 2.0.0.

I want to fail in this case. I am aware of `failOnVersionConflict()`, but this raises errors even when the patch segments don’t match. How can I fail only when there is major version conflict?

Thanks

Comment: You could adapt the following example to check if the major version of the requested dependency is different than the one you want and fail instead of forcing a version.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the example: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#example_blacklisting_a_version_with_a_replacement

Comment: have you managed to sort it out? the link above is dead

Comment: The only way that I know of to do this would be do add some kind of version processor hook

Comment: Did you find a solution after all?

Comment: @peshkira See my previous comment.

Comment: Yes thanks. Unfortunately, it is not very helpful. I am trying to research Gradle's Rich versions and they might help, but the problem is that they are not compatible with Maven unless you use Gradle Module Metadata. So I am trying also to figure out if there is another way. Your comment does not help me right now, but if you have a specific idea or example or link, it will be much appreciated, @GreenSaguaro.

Comment: I am not sure ultimately what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps look at the Gradle Spring BOM plugin. This code may dive deep into the API of intercepting and changing dependency versions. Additionally, I would explore the Gradle API https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html and the Gradle DSL https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html. @peshkira